# Repeat function indefinitely in a column until values reach certain level

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
  grade   type
0 402     A
1 312     B
2 321     C
...
```

If the type is A and the value in grade column if higher than 100 I want to multiply it by 0.7 indefinitely until it gets to a value below 100. I didn't find a good way to do that, right now I'm using this code below:

```
df.loc[(df['type'] == 'A') & (df['grade'] > 100),'grade'] = df['grade']*0.7
(I repeat that 100 times and cross my fingers for 'grade' to be below 100)
```

I could just do that a few times and if it didn't reach I would force to be 100, however I don't want to have a lot of equal values in the df and also I can't put a random component in it.

Is there a better way to do that (preferably with Pandas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the power needed using [`np.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html)(natural logarithm), with which you can further calculate the multiplier needed to bring down the value under `100`:

```
df.loc[df.type.eq('A') & df.grade.gt(100), 'grade'] = df.grade * np.power(0.7, np.floor(np.log(100 / df.grade) / np.log(0.7)) + 1)

df
#      grade type
#0   96.5202    A
#1  312.0000    B
#2  321.0000    C
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row['type'] == 'A':
       grade = row['grade']
       while grade > 100:
           grade = grade*.7
       df.loc[index, 'grade'] = grade
```

Answer (score 0):

@Psidom's suggestion is interesting and it certainly works, however I wanted something more simple and also I wanted to avoid going to Numpy.
Using @ykrueng's suggestion as inspiration, I found a way to run exactly what I wanted:

```
while len((df.loc[(df['type'] == 'A') & (df['grade'] > 100)]).index)>0:
    df.loc[(df['type'] == 'A') & (df['grade'] > 100),'grade'] = df['grade']*0.7
```